# Why is performing synthetic division of polynomials acceptable when one may be zero? ${}$

Tags: quadratics

So there is a typical problem in quadratic equations. Consider one as an example:

If $x=3 +\sqrt 5$ then find $x^4 -12x^3 +44x^2 -48x +17$.

The solution is pretty simple and a similar approach is put forward in another problem in complex numbers. Certainly we proceed by squaring $x=3 +\sqrt 5$ to reach $x^2 -6x +4 =0$.

Then by Synthetic Division/Division Algorithm we reach as follows:
$x^4 -12x^3 +44x^2 -48x +17 = (x^2 -6x +4)(x^2 -6x +4) + 1$.

But since $x^2 -6x +4 = 0$ then the above expression reduces to 1, that’s the answer.

But we did remembered the above formula as Dividend = Divisor $\times$ Quotient + Remainder.
Now the Divisor ($x^2 -6x +4$ in this case) ${} = 0$, then how come we can divide something by zero ($0$)?
Pardon me for any mistake I am just first question new to stack exchange world.
Please do tell me how do we insert mathematical symbols in the question.

Thank You

Comment: Please use mathjax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: You can divide $x^2-1$ by $x-1$ as a **polynomial**, although for the value $x=1$ this is not allowed. The result is $x+1\in K[x]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot #Paul Frost

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x) = x^4 -12*x^3 +44*x^2 -48*x +17.$

Let $\displaystyle g(x) = x- \left(3 +\sqrt{5}\right).$

Let $h(x) = [g(x)]^2.$

When you divide $f(x)$ by $h(x)$, you are **not** evaluating the function $f(x)$ at any particular value of $(x)$, or evaluating $h(x)$ at any particular value of $(x)$.

Instead, you are treating $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ as **polynomial functions**, that are each members of the field of such polynomial functions (of finite degree), where each coefficient of the corresponding function is a Real number.

This is totally different than performing the evaluation of one or more of the polynomial functions at specific values of $(x)$, and then performing a division, based on such an evaluation.

---

As a much simpler example,

let $j(x) = x-1$ and let $k(x) = x^2 - 3x + 2.$

Then $j(x)$ is a factor of $k(x)$ even though $j(1) = 0 = k(1).$

Answer (score 2):

You are doing polynomial long division, and while the divisor quadratic may be zero at $x=3+\sqrt5$, it is *not zero* in general, so you need not worry about division by zero.

Polynomial long division only performs actual, arithmetic divisions in the *field of coefficients*, not the ring of polynomials. The successive reductions of degree of the dividend are a sequence of multiplications by powers of $x$ and subtractions, not involving divisions. (Hence the alternative name "Euclidean division".)

Answer (score 2):

You do the operations without using the word "division". Instead use the words "substitution" and "elimination".

Having found that $x^2-6x+4=0$,rearrange this to give

$x^2=6x-4.$

Now in your polynomial function

$f(x)=x^4-12x^3+44x^2-48x+17,$

you use the quadratic equation to render

$x^4=6x^3-4x^2$

and then eliminate the $x^4$ term from $f(x)$:

$f(x)=(6x^3-4x^2)-12x^3+44x^2-48x+17=-6x^3+40x^2-48x+17.$

In subsequent steps we use the relations

$x^3=6x^2-4x$

$x^2=6x-4$

to eliminate the cubic and then the quadratic terms in the same way. Thus without using any division operation and therefore without any issue with division by zero. We reduce $f(x)$ to $Ax+B$ for some constants $A$ and $B$. In this case $A=0,B=1$ so we get $1$ as our final result; but if $A$ were not zero the evaluation still would have been much simpler that directly substituting into the fourth-degree polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of algebraic fractions called $\Bbb R(x)$ which, roughly speaking, is the set of quotients of polynomials $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where we consider $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\dfrac{P'(x)}{Q'(x)}$ when $P(x)Q'(x)=P'(x)Q(x)$. (The symbol $'$ is has nothing to do with derivatives here).

In this set $x$ is not a number, just a symbol. It is possible that $Q$ divides $P$, and in this case $\dfrac{P(x)/Q(x)}{1}=\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, just like we consider the fraction $\dfrac 62$ equal to the integer number $3$.

On the other side, we have *rational functions*, that are quotients of polynomial functions.

For example, the function
$$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}\text{ for }x\neq 1$$
is a rational function that is it not defined ad $x=1$ because the denominator becomes $0$ for that value. And the function
$$\tilde f(x)=x+1\text{ for }x\in\Bbb R$$
is a polynomial function and its domain is $\Bbb R$.

Since the expressions of the functions, as algebraic fractions, are equivalent, $f(a)=\tilde f(a)$ for $a\neq 1$, but for $a=1$, $f(1)$ is not defined but $\tilde f(1)=2$

To sum up, as algebraic fractions $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $x+1$ are the same, but as functions, $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $\tilde f(x)=x+1$, are not.